# How to free-draw a line in three.js r144 on mouse move, and using BufferGeometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using code from this repo - [scribble](https://github.com/esperanc/scribble.git), which is using three.js r87.  I followed the [Updating THREE.Geometry to THREE.BufferGeometry](https://sbcode.net/threejs/geometry-to-buffergeometry/) tutorial in order to upgrade the code to three.js r144.  I've got one function correct, but the other one is giving me trouble.

The mousePressed function was easy to update:

```js
function mousePressed() {
  const point = new THREE.Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 0);
  // const geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  // geometry.vertices.push(point);
  let points = [];
  points.push(point);
  let geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
  const line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
  scene.add(line);
  selected = line;
}
```

But I updated mouseDragged(), and I don't understand why it's not working:

```js
function mouseDragged() {
  const line = selected;
  const point = new THREE.Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 0);
  const oldgeometry = line.geometry;
  // const newgeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  // newgeometry.vertices = oldgeometry.vertices;
  // newgeometry.vertices.push(point);
  let newgeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  let positions = oldgeometry.attributes.position.array;
  for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i += 3) {
    const v = new THREE.Vector3(positions[i], positions[i + 1], positions[i + 2]);
    positions[i] = v.x;
    positions[i + 1] = v.y;
    positions[i + 2] = v.z;
  }
  positions.push(point); // I should just be able to add the new point, no?
  newgeometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
  line.geometry = newgeometry;
  scene.add(line); // I re-added the line, just in case. But the line does not show up, whether or not I do this.
  selected = line;
}
```

Help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from the resource is highly inefficient since you continuously allocate geometries all the time without disposal management which will lead to a memory leak. Try the following approach:

```js
let camera, scene, renderer, line;

const frustumSize = 4;

let index = 0;
const coords = new THREE.Vector3();

init();
render();

function init() {

  const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

  camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(frustumSize * aspect / -2, frustumSize * aspect / 2, frustumSize / 2, frustumSize / -2, 0.1, 20);
  camera.position.z = 5;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

  const positionAttribute = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(1000 * 3), 3); // allocate large enough buffer
  positionAttribute.setUsage(THREE.DynamicDrawUsage);
  geometry.setAttribute('position', positionAttribute);

  const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial()

  line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
  scene.add(line);

  // initial points

  addPoint(0, 0, 0); // start point
  addPoint(1, 0, 0); // current pointer coordinate

  //

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  renderer.domElement.addEventListener('pointerdown', onPointerDown);
  renderer.domElement.addEventListener('pointermove', onPointerMove);

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

}

function addPoint(x, y, z) {

  const positionAttribute = line.geometry.getAttribute('position');
  positionAttribute.setXYZ(index, x, y, z);
  positionAttribute.needsUpdate = true;

  index++;

  line.geometry.setDrawRange(0, index);

}

function updatePoint(x, y, z) {

  const positionAttribute = line.geometry.getAttribute('position');
  positionAttribute.setXYZ(index - 1, coords.x, coords.y, 0);
  positionAttribute.needsUpdate = true;

}

function onPointerDown(event) {

  coords.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  coords.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  coords.z = (camera.near + camera.far) / (camera.near - camera.far);

  coords.unproject(camera);

  addPoint(coords.x, coords.y, 0);

  render();

}

function onPointerMove(event) {

  coords.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  coords.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  coords.z = (camera.near + camera.far) / (camera.near - camera.far);

  coords.unproject(camera);

  updatePoint(coords.x, coords.y, 0)

  render();

}

function onWindowResize() {

  const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

  camera.left = -frustumSize * aspect / 2;
  camera.right = frustumSize * aspect / 2;
  camera.top = frustumSize / 2;
  camera.bottom = -frustumSize / 2;

  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  render();

}

function render() {

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.144/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

The idea is to allocate a single large buffer to store all current and future points of a line. You then use `setDrawRange()` to define, what parts of the buffer should be rendered.

Comment: thank you for coming to my rescue.  Just out of curiosity, why do we set frustumSize to 4 in this case?  Also please forgive my ignorance, but could you please explain why, when setting camera orientation, we do like `frustumSize * aspect / -2`?

Comment: You can set `frustumSize` to whatever value you need. It just defines the size of the orthographic projection. The `frustumSize * aspect / -2` stuff just computes the side planes of the view frustum. You have to honor the desired size as well as the aspect ratio.